# " function was not declared in this scope" error when declaring a function in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I wrote a function to control dc motors in my project but keep getting this error when I compile my code.

```
error: 'mPower' was not declared in this scope
   mPower(leftSpeed, rightSpeed);
error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
   void mPower(int m1, int m2){
error: expected '}' at end of input
 }
mPower' was not declared in this scope
```

I tried defining & declaring the function before calling it.

```
void loop() {

mPower(leftSpeed, rightSpeed);


  void mPower(int m1, int m2){
      // ... some instructions ...
  }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the `mPower` function outside your `loop`:

```
// motor functionings
void mPower(int m1, int m2){
    // Left Motor
    if(m1 > 0){ //left motor move foward
        digitalWrite(IN1,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(IN2,LOW);
    }else{ ////left motor move backward
        digitalWrite(IN1,LOW);
        digitalWrite(IN2,HIGH );
        m1 = m1*-1; //convert m1 into positive value
    }
    analogWrite(ENA,m1); //set pwm value according to m1

    //Right Motor
    if(m2 > 0){   //right motor move foward
        digitalWrite(IN3,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(IN4,LOW);
    }else{        //right motor move backward
        digitalWrite(IN3,LOW);
        digitalWrite(IN4,HIGH );
        m2 = m2*-1; //convert m2 into positive value
    }
    analogWrite(ENB,m2); //set pwm value according to m2

}

void loop() {
    mPower(leftSpeed, rightSpeed);
}
```